# Is their an equivalent of a Java servlet in Classic ASP or how would I simulate one?

Tags: session, asp-classic

I'm assigned the task of implementing session checking for a Classic ASP application. I don't want to include session checking on every single page.

I'd rather use something that's akin to a servlet or servlet filter in Java. The problem is I don't know of any implementation in Classic ASP which approximates this effect. Must I check for an existing session in each and every page or is there something I can do on an application-wide level which will check the request?

I was thinking of creating a URL rewrite rule which forwards every request to a page which checks the session and either redirect if there is no session or forwards the user to the requested URL if a session exists. Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to add the check to the top of every page with asp classic.

Comment: Ugh. What about if some of the pages happen to end with .html? In that case, is there some way I tell IIS to treat the .html extension as if they were .asp so classic asp code can run?

Comment: I think there is a way to do that actually. You could also redirect all .html to files of the same name but with .asp extension and get rid of the .html files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IIS rewrite rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) for this purpose.

Create a simple rewrite rule like this:

```
<rule name="Rewrite html">
    <match url="/(.*)\.html$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.asp" />
</rule>
```

You'll have to consider the directory structure, you are using. Then decide where to put the web.config rules and adjust above rule accordingly.